# MVC Telerik Grid Format column bool to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik, telerik-grid

Is it possible to format a Boolean to string in a Telerik Grid?

I need to change the value of a Boolean (true/false) to string (Yes/No).

My model:

```
[DataMember]
[DisplayName("PANDORA")]
public bool SeVePandora { get; set; }
[DataMember]
[DisplayName("PORTOS")]
public bool SeVePortos { get; set; }
[DataMember]
[DisplayName("CARRIER")]
public bool SeVeCarrier { get; set; }
[DataMember]
[DisplayName("CALCULADORA")]
public bool SeVeCalculadora { get; set; }
[DataMember]
[DisplayName("CONTROL STOCK")]
public bool SeVeControlStock { get; set; }
[DataMember]
[DisplayName("REMARKETING")]
public bool SeVeRemarketing { get; set; }
[DataMember]
[DisplayName("AUTO CREDIT")]
public bool SeVeAutocredit { get; set; }
[DataMember]
[DisplayName("VALORES RESIDUALES")]
public bool SeVeValoresResiduales { get; set; }
[DataMember]
[DisplayName("PRUEBAS")]
public bool EntornoPruebas { get; set; }
```

My View:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid<VWIS.DataModels.Models.AvisosPromociones.Avisos>()
.Name("ListAvisos")
.Columns(columna =>
    {
        columna.Bound(d => d.IdAViso).Visible(false).Sortable(false);
        columna.Bound(d => d.Titulo).Width(380).Sortable(false);
        columna.Bound(d => d.FechaInicio).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").Width(95).Sortable(true);
        columna.Bound(d => d.FechaFin).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").Width(86).Sortable(true);
        columna.Bound(d => d.SeVePandora).Width(50).Sortable(false);
        columna.Bound(d => d.SeVePortos).Width(50).Sortable(false);
        columna.Bound(d => d.EntornoPruebas).Width(50).Sortable(false);
        columna.Bound(d => d.SeVeCarrier).Width(50).Sortable(false);
        columna.Bound(d => d.SeVeCalculadora).Width(50).Sortable(false);
        columna.Bound(d => d.SeVeControlStock).Width(50).Sortable(false);
        columna.Bound(d => d.SeVeRemarketing).Width(50).Sortable(false);
        columna.Bound(d => d.SeVeAutocredit).Width(50).Sortable(false);
        columna.Bound(d => d.SeVeValoresResiduales).Width(50).Sortable(false);
        }).DataBinding(datos => datos.Ajax().Select("_BusquedaAvisos", "Avisos", new { PrimeraBusqueda = true }))
                   .Pageable(page => page.PageSize(10))
                   .Selectable()
                   .Sortable()
                   .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
                   .ClientEvents(e => e.OnDataBinding("OnDataBinding").OnRowSelect("SeleccionarFila"))

%>
```

In `columna.Bound(d => d.SeVePandora).Format()` lambda expresions are not allowed.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code @jayesh-goyani. Telerik Grid needs a '<' to open logic in `.ClientTemplate`

```
`colums.Bound(d => d.SeVePandora).Width(50).Sortable(false).ClientTemplate(
    "<# if (SeVePandora == true) { #>" +
        "<span>Yes</span>" +
    "<# } else { #>" +
        "<span>No</span>" +
    "<# } #>"
);`
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have the same problem and my code, the same as yours, does not work: columns.Bound(cb => cb.Status).Width(60).ClientTemplate(
                    "<# if (Status == true) { #>" +
                        "<span>Active</span>" +
                    "<# } else { #>" +
                        "<span>Inactive</span>" +
                    "<# } #>"
                ); I get a JavaScript error that states "Status is not defined." If I remove the client template, the boolean field renders properly, albeit with true/false rendered.

Answer (score 2):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
colums.Bound(d => d.SeVePandora).Width(50).Sortable(false).ClientTemplate(
    "# if (SeVePandora == true) { #" +
        "<span>Yes</span>" +
    "# } else { #" +
        "<span>No</span>" +
    "# } #"
);
```

For more information please [this](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-have-conditional-logic-in-a-column-client-template?) link.

Comment: This code doesn't works. I have Telerik Components and faqs are for Kendo

Comment: I will provide working demo later. Your requirement is in bool field you want to display yes/no?

Comment: Yes, `bool` field **must** be a string yes/no.

Answer (score 2):

Only Client Template can be even simpler as bellow.

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Required).Width(65)
    .ClientTemplate("#= Price > 0 ? Required ? 'Yes' : 'No' : 'N/A'#");
```

In my example I check two things if price is more then zero and if required as I have three options.